# Android ListView with EditText focus issues

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext, focusable

I have a question, why can't we have `EditText`s inside `ListView`s (in the `ListView` items) ?

Every time I had this thing to do I had to do a lot of "hacks" to make it work and still I have a lot of focus issues..

I saw a lot of posts on stack and on google with some fixes but if you test this throughly you will notice a lot of bugs..

Does anyone know a good tutorial on how to make this really work? Or at least give a different design for this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: what "hacks" do you mean?

Comment: @Cata - Did you follow the link here - http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/android-focusable-edittext-inside-listview/ ? I think that the guy there has the solution..

Comment: @ g00dy Thanks for the link, I tried that allready and if you like to add some buttons below the edittext, that won't work..
@ pskink just saving the position of the selected EditText in the Adapter and set the focus back on the EditText on getView when needed.. also I made a custom keyboard(not IME but layouts) once but the focus was still a problem